# Compras integradas(IAP) en juego no funcionan en la Alpha

Tags: unity3d, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

He introducido compras integradas(IAP) en mi juego. He probado que funcionaban correctamente los botones de compra utilizando la consola de Unity imprimiendo "Has comprado monedas.". Como todo iba bien he subido una Alpha a Google Play Store para confirmar que todo estaba bien, pero los botones de compra no hacen nada. En la descripción de la ficha de la Play Store dice que el juego tiene compras integradas(por lo que está bien implementado). Algo curioso es que los botones emiten sonido al ser pulsados pero los botones de la alpha que he subido no reproducen el sonido, por lo que entiendo que los botones están bloqueados por alguna razón, impidiendo ser pulsados.
No sé qué puede estar fallando, puede ser por usar la firma del certificado de subida en vez del certificado de firma de aplicaciones?

Comment: encontraste solución? Me pasa lo mismo
Un saludo.

Comment: Hola,
No me acuerdo exactamente de como lo he resuelto ya que fue hace 6 meses, pero recuerdo que estaba todo bien programado. Tuve varios problemas en los que las cosas no funcionaban a pesar de estar bien hechas, y lo solucioné actualizando todo lo que podía actualizar (Unity Hub y utilizar la última versión de Unity) porque en algunas versiones antiguas o betas no funcionan las cosas. En otras ocasiones me pasaba que la ruta de una clave no era la correcta como por ejemplo la Variable de entorno Path. En otra ocasión el error era una mayúscula como primera letra del nombre de un archivo.

Comment: Asegúrate también de que estás usando la clave correcta y el lanzamiento correcto.
Coméntame si conseguiste que funcionara y si no podemos seguir mirando a ver si encontramos el error.